# How can I make increment for boostrap area-controls tag increment from thymeleaf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I need to make increment in area-controls boostrap taf with my list count.
My code as under:

```
<th:block th:each="stateTitles, statesStatus: ${states}">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" id="stateCollapsed" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" th:href="'#collapse' + ${statesStatus.index + 1}" 
        aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="'collapse' + ${statesStatus.index + 1}">
        <span id="state" th:text="${stateTitles}" /> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span>
    </a>
</th:block>
```

Increment is not working for area-controls tag.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: <th:block th:each="stateTitles, statesStatus: ${states}">

<a data-toggle="collapse" id="stateCollapsed" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" th:href="'#collapse' + ${statesStatus.index + 1}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="'collapse' + ${statesStatus.index + 1}">
          <span id="state" th:text="${stateTitles}" /> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span>
         </a>

</th:block>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `th:attr` in order to inject values using Thymeleaf, check documentation [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-attribute-values).

So change the code to:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" id="stateCollapsed" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" th:href="'#collapse' + ${statesStatus.index + 1}" 
        aria-expanded="true" th:attr="aria-controls='collapse' + ${statesStatus.index + 1}">
```

Comment: Hi Patrick LC,
I need to add thymeleaf list size in bootstrap data-slider-max = list.size,
How can I add it?
I tried with th:attr="data-slider-max=${list.size}", but not working.
Even the list attribute set in spring model is not printing size in any text tag.